# is it good practice to encode user input to database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am wondering if it is consider good practice to encode user input to database.

Or is it ok to not encode to user input instead.

Currently my way of doing it is to encode it when entering database and use Html.DisplayFor to display it.

Comment: Rule of thumb: "encode" information *when* it is used *in context* of how it is used. (For SQL this is using placeholders, not "encoding"; then when emitting the data to the HTML make sure it is properly HTML-escaped/"encoded".)

Comment: perhaps i make it more clear. let say user input <b>String</b> is it good practice to change the user input into &lt;b&gt;String&lt;/b&gt; before inserting it into database

Comment: Not really. You have to concern yourself with html decoding on output to different destinations. You DO want to protect against sql injection protection and cross site scripting, but that can be mitigated by using parameterized queries into the database.  Also if you do decide to neuter html or script tags, you only need to attack the less-than tag, not both.   It neutralizes the tag just the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You want to keep the input in its original form until you need it and know what the output type is.  It might be HTML for now, but later if you want to change it to json, text file, xml, etc the encoding might make it look different then you want.

So, first you want to make sure you are securely validating your input.  It is a good idea to know what are the requirements for each of your inputs and validate that they are withing the correct length, range, character set, etc.  It will be to your interest to limit the type of characters that are allowed as valid characters of an input type.  (If using Regular Expressions to validate input ensure you do not use a regular expressions that is susceptible to a [Regular Expression Denial of Service](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS).

When moving the data around in your code ensure that you are properly handling the data in a manner that it will not turn into an [Injection Attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A1-Injection).

Since you are talking about a database, the best practice is to use paramaterized statements.  Check out the prevention methods in the above link.

Then when it comes outputting using MVC, if you are not using RAW or MvcHtmlString functions/calls, then the output is automatically encoded.  With the automatic encoding, you want to make sure you are using the AntiXss encoder and not the default (whitelist approach vs. blacklist). [Link](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new#_Toc318097382)

If you are using Raw or MvcHtmlString, you want to make sure you COMPLETE TRUST the values (you hard coded them in) or you manually encode them using the AntiXss Encoder class.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not necessary to encode all the user inputs, rather if you want to avoid the script injection either you my try to validate the fields for special characters like '<', '>', '/', etc. else your Html helper method itself will do the needful.